# Proxying arguments from one function to a command

Tags: fish

I have function `bajouras.fish` which calls another function, let's say `scarabosses`:

```
function bajouras
  scarabosses "someCMD" $argv
end
```

so the function `scarabosses` will get the first argument "someCMD" and any extra arguments passed to `bajouras`.

Inside `scarabosses` I'm doing something like this:

```
function scarabosses
  if test "$count" -ge 2
    set args $argv[2..-1]
  else
    set args ""
  end

  eval (type -fP $argv[1]) $args
end
```

Now the problem is that if I pass some string to the `bajouras`

`bajouras -v -t "some cool (string)"`

and echo the `$argv` my string although is a parameter, no longer is a string. So by the time I pass that to `scarabosses` this is what I get:

```
someCMD -v -t some cool (string)
```

And since I'm no longer passing a string to `scarabosses` fish will try to do some command substitution and I will get an error.

Is there a way to ensure that whatever I pass to `bajouras` will stay that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `eval` is the cause of your problem. That just takes all of its arguments and interprets them as if they were given on the commandline, i.e. it tokenizes it again, performs expansions, etc.

I recommend avoiding `eval` if you can, which you cannot in this case (currently).

What you should do here is to use `string escape` to safeguard any arguments you don't want `eval` to interpret again:

```
   eval (string escape -- (type -fP $argv[1]) $args)
```

(I'm also escaping the `type -fP` here since it could contain spaces that eval would split on)

Comment: Note: The current consensus in upstream fish is to allow expansions-as-commands if they are "decorated" in some way, e.g. `$PAGER somefile` would still be forbidden, but `command $PAGER somefile` or a proposed `call $PAGER somefile` would be allowed. That would remove the need for `eval` here.

Comment: I'm just using eval because I wanted somehow to be able to call a command from a string passed by another function

Comment: Yes, and it's currently necessary for that. It's just that you need to `string escape` the arguments. I know it's not pretty.

Comment: Well as long as it works and it's more or less readable I'm happy with that. BTW, thanks that worked perfectly fine!

Comment: My decoration workaround is to create an alias: `alias __cmd $some_command; __cmd $argv; functions -e __cmd`

Comment: Which basically does that `string escape | source` dance in the background - see `type alias`.